# Proper way to get groups of a user in linux using C

Tags: c, linux, usergroups

I want to know if there is any alternate C library for the unix command groups,

`$ groups  ---- lists all the group id's of the user.`

There is a method called getgroups() but it returns the groups of the user this method. Is there a way to get groups for a particular user using C.

Comment: "getgrent, setgrent, endgrent - get group file entry" with "getpwent, setpwent, endpwent - get password file entry"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include "<grp.h>"
int getgrouplist(const char *user, gid_t group, gid_t *groups, int *ngroups);
```

Comment: For completeness: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html Also mind the bug (See the man-pages for details)

Comment: Sorry but could you tell me how I can get groupid in order to use getgrouplist method? All I have is the username

Comment: @AdiGuN, The man page has a code example that tells you how you get that information.

Comment: Maybe try putting a useful example instead of an manpage excerpt.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a example of how to do it using [getgrouplist](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html), feel free to ask anything.

```
__uid_t uid = getuid();//you can change this to be the uid that you want

struct passwd* pw = getpwuid(uid);
if(pw == NULL){
    perror("getpwuid error: ");
}

int ngroups = 0;

//this call is just to get the correct ngroups
getgrouplist(pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid, NULL, &ngroups);
__gid_t groups[ngroups];

//here we actually get the groups
getgrouplist(pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups);


//example to print the groups name
for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
    struct group* gr = getgrgid(groups[i]);
    if(gr == NULL){
        perror("getgrgid error: ");
    }
    printf("%s\n",gr->gr_name);
}
```

Comment: i dont see how this compiles? you cant dynamically allocate the groups array in that way? you would need a new there?

Comment: If I recall correctly I was having some issues with dynamic (heap) allocation, so I tried allocating it in the stack and worked correctly.

Comment: ah I see. I guess my point really is that the code line `__gid_t groups[ngroups];` should throw an error regarding ngroups not being known at compile time. The code above is attempting to dynamically allocate on the stack which doesnt really make sense.

Comment: Maybe this only works on c++. I didn't think about that possibility. If you manage to get it working on c, maybe with [alloca](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/alloca.3.html), edit my answer or post another one.

Comment: Variable-length arrays were added in C99.