# setgid(): Operation not permitted

Tags: c, unix

My task is to list all the groups that a user is a member of, for all users on the system. The idea is to go through `/etc/passwd` and for every user print its groups.

[EDIT] This did the trick:

```
if( getgrouplist(passwd->pw_name, passwd->pw_gid,
                    groups, &ngroups) < 0)
  error_fatal ("getgrouplist ()");
```

Yet I'm still curious about the reason it's not working.

Output:

```
User root is a member of: root
User daemon is a member of: root
setgid(): Operation not permitted
```

Code:

```
while ((passwd = getpwent ()) != NULL) {
    uid = passwd->pw_uid;
    gid = passwd->pw_gid;

    if (setgid(gid) < 0)
        error_fatal ("setgid()");

    if (setuid(uid) < 0)
        error_fatal ("setuid()");

    if((ngroups = getgroups (0, NULL)) < 0)
        error_fatal ("getgroups ()");

    if((groups = (gid_t *) malloc (sizeof (gid_t) * ngroups)) < 0)
        error_fatal ("malloc ()");

    if (getgroups (ngroups, groups) < 0)
        error_fatal ("getgroups ()");

    printf ("User %s is a member of: ", passwd->pw_name);
    for (i = 0; i < ngroups; i++) {
        gid = groups[i];
        if((group = getgrgid (gid)) == NULL)
            error_fatal ("getgrgid ()");
        printf ("%s ", group->gr_name);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to get groups of a user in linux using C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104383/proper-way-to-get-groups-of-a-user-in-linux-using-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once your program calls `setuid()` to switch to another user other than `root`, your program has given up its permission to switch users so subsequent calls will fail.

Comment: Oh..so this is not a good way to do it, I see. Thank you a lot!